# WordPress run php code into the_content loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm learning PHP and WordPress development, so I assumed that maybe here I'll find the answer or a tip.

I've restriced `the_content` based on user role. After the end of `the_content` I'd like to display button whitch is unique to the specific post. So here is the code which display that:

```
function displaycontent($content) {
    if(is_singular( 'custom_post_type' )) {

        $aftercontent = 'I Want To Add Code Here';
        $fullcontent =  $content . $aftercontent;

    } else {
        $fullcontent = $content;
    }

    return $fullcontent;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'displaycontent');
```

And I'd like to insert code below into the underlined place above:

```
<?php 
$post = $wp_query->post;   
$group_id = get_field( 'link_number' , $post->ID );   
if( $group_id ) {
   echo do_shortcode( '[checkout_button class="button" level="' . $group_id . '" text="Order"]' ); 
}
?>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably better to create a custom shortcode for this. If you change how `the_content` works, it will be global, everywhere.

***Note:**

This code is completely untested and put together after 5 min of Googling, so if somehting is wrong, feel free to comment and I'll amend it. It should be fairly close and is mostly for explaining the concept instead of a pure copy/paste solution*

**Register a new shortcode:**

```
add_shortcode('my_awesome_content', 'my_awesome_content_func');
```

**Create the callback function:**

Here we've added `$atts` which will contain our attribute (the post id):

```
function my_awesome_content_func($atts = [])
{
    $postId = $atts['postid'] ?? null;

    if ($postId === null) {
        // We got no id so let's bail
        return null;
    }

    $post = get_post($postId);

    if (!$post) {
        // We didn't find any post with the id so again, let's bail
        return null;
    }

    $group_id = get_field( 'link_number' , $post->ID );   

    $content = $post->content;

    if( $group_id ) {
        $content .= do_shortcode( '[checkout_button class="button" level="' . $group_id . '" text="Order"]' ); 
    }

    return $content;
}
```

**Usage:**

Now you should be able to call it like this:

```
echo do_shortcode('[my_awesome_content postid="' . $post->ID . '"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just embed you code below in the above filter with some modifications:

```
function displaycontent($content) {
    if (is_singular('custom_post_type')) {

        $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
        $group_id = get_field('link_number', $post_id);
        $aftercontent = '';
        if ($group_id)
            $aftercontent = do_shortcode('[checkout_button class="button" level="'.$group_id. '" text="Order"]');
        $fullcontent = $content.$aftercontent;

    } else {
        $fullcontent = $content;
    }

    return $fullcontent;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'displaycontent');
```

Comment: Not exactly. Your code is ok, but this function I need to implement should be inserted into $aftercontent = 'Right Here'.

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks everyone, I Got it! Here is the code if anyone would have same problem:

```
function displaycontent($content) {
    if(is_singular( 'custom_post_type' )) {
        $group_id = get_field('link_number');
        $aftercontent = do_shortcode( '[checkout_button class="button" level="' . $group_id . '" text="Order"]' );
        $fullcontent = $beforecontent . $content . $aftercontent;

} else {
    $fullcontent = $content;
}

    return $fullcontent;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'displaycontent');
```